# Joomla - Article not showing up

Tags: joomla

I have published some articles on Joomla and added theme to module at homepage. But when i click a link, it just show up home page, not article content.

My website here http://vmfederation.com/ and i use template JD Chicago. Example: http://vmfederation.com/23-capabilities/23-why-work-with-us.html

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: you probably have the wrong template selected for that page. Other pages are working like : http://vmfederation.com/services/tailored-sourcing-with-in-house-capabilities.html

Comment: I have used the same Template Style ( Default Template ) for this page and another page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the menu link: http://vmfederation.com/services/why-work-with-us.html
Capabilities does not have this item